# Manually set different time and date in Microsoft Outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook, calendar, task

Is it possible to manually set a different time and date for Microsoft Outlook Professional Plus 2016? I'm using a data file without an email account. I'd like to manually change the time and date and see task notifications, alarms, and calendar events react accordingly. Is this possible without changing the time and date on my computer? If so, how?

Comment: Time and date of what? Creation and modification times of various Outlook items? You cannot do that. Is this a programming question?

Comment: I want Microsoft Outlook to use a different time and date than the one set within Windows. I'd be pleased if I could set this time and date using  the Outlook interface or through programming. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the Calendar folder show more than one time zone (File | Options | Calendar | Time zones), but for everything else Outlook uses the local time zone and date/time, just like it should.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer.